# WPF ListView Button customization item by item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, button

i have a data source from a DB and i want to display it in a list view.
In this list view i want a column with a button but i want the button to change it's content and bhaviour based on data i have in another table on that DB.
so if my list view is:

```
<ListView x:Name="usersListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="followColumn" Header="follow" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="followButton" Content="Follow"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <!--OTHER COLUMNS...-->
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

is there i way i can access all the followButton present in my usersListView one by one and change their content, tag, ecc...?

Comment: Are you using MVVM ?

Comment: i'm using EntityFramework @AabidAli

Comment: Ok i was about to suggest using different Datatemplates for each of your types. But it guess you are binding to EF models directly. So maybe you could bind to a converter which would return the required content when applying the template.

Comment: To what do you want to set the `Content`? Where does this data come from?  Please improve your example with more details.